# Working with merge cells to filter data in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter some data using row 4 as the column headers. The problem here is that I have some cells that are merged between row 2 and 3. When I try filtering for row 4, the VBA code filters row 2 instead of row 3. I was recording a few steps of turning on the filter for Row 3, and then selecting a few criteria to filter for in some of the columns. This is the code which was produced by the excel VBA recorder.

code:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Range("D3").Activate
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$G$8").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("1", _
        "3", "4"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$G$8").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="M"
End Sub
```

How this code was produced and how was the data structured:
I prepared a simple worksheet which more or less faces the same difficulty. The data is structured in the same way as captured in the following screenshot.

[image]

All I did was select row 3, turn on the filter mode, and did some filtering in the columns. That is how the vba code was produced.

[image]

However, when I run the same VBA code that was produced against the data, I get this as the results.

[image]

We can see that it is taking row 2 as the header instead of row 3. What is the problem here?

Comment: I changed the screenshots, hopefully the merge cells are clearer. @Damian is there no way to work with the merge cells?

Comment: I was wrong, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because when you tell the macro to select row 3 is selecting rows 2 and 3.

Check it out, debug your code using F8 and after the `Rows("3:3").Select` you will see both rows selected.

To avoid this and so many errors you shouldn't use  `.Select` or `.Activate`

Here is how:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Macro1()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Datos") 'change the name to your working sheet
        If .AutoFilterMode = True Then .AutoFilterMode = False 'first check that there are no filters
        .Range("$A$3:$G$8").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("1", _
        "3", "4"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Range("$A$3:$G$8").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="M"
    End With

End Sub
```

Also while we are at it, using `Option Explicit` will force you to declare variables to avoid errors. And an [extended answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) on how to avoid using select.

Comment: The column header for row 3 still gets hidden which I am trying to avoid. I did debug the code using F8. The line `Rows("3:3").Select` selects both rows, but is there a way to force it to select the second row instead of the first?

Answer (score 1):

You need not use a selection of rows separately.

```
Sub Macro1()

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$G$8").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("1", _
    "3", "4"), Operator:=xlOr
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$G$8").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="M"

End Sub
```